# How can I generate random int numbers within a set range (without duplicates!) within a class constructor?

Tags: c++, class, random, constructor

I am self-learning C++ from a text book and I have a problem to solve, outlined below.

I have the following class structure:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdio>
 #include <ctime> 

 using namespace std;


   class classroom{

     char name[25];
     int student_id;
     float grades[10];
     float average;
     int num_tests;
     float letter_grade;

   public:       
     void enter_name_id(void);
     void enter_grade(void);
     void average_grades(void);
     void letter_grades(void);
     void output_name_id_grade(void);
     classroom();

   };
```

And I have the following Constructor for the above class:

```
 classroom::classroom(){

      int i;

      srand((unsigned)time(0));
      int random_integer=0; 
      random_integer = (rand()%5) + (rand()%5); 

      num_tests=0;
      average=0.0;

      for(i=0;i<10;i++){

        grades[i]=0.0;

      }

      for(i=0;i<27;i++){

         name[i]='-';       
      }
      cout<<"\n*****************Finished*****************";
 }
```

There will be 3 students of this class structure declared in the `main`:

```
int main()
{       
  classroom students[3]; 
//and so...

}
```

I need to generate a unique student ID for each student in the constructor within a range of values, say, 0 to 10.

I have copied the following code snippet into the constructor. It generates my random number for me within the desired range:

```
srand((unsigned)time(0));
  int random_integer=0; 
  random_integer = (rand()%5) + (rand()%5);
```

The problem is that I need to get rid of any duplicates within the range of random numbers that are generated.

Comment: Correction: int random_integer=0; should read  int random_integer;

Comment: Why do you 1) use this sum of 2 random numbers (which is basically *not* giving you a random number in the desired range) 2) assume a random number can serve as an identifier ?

Comment: Just a little note, the class name is very misleading -- the object appears to be closer to a `student` than a `classroom`.  You should consider naming your classes just as you would describe them -- in this case, they represent and contain data about a student -- so they should be named something like `Student`.

Comment: re:correction -- initializing it to 0 and then setting it equal to something else is fine and actually a good coding practice.

Comment: Not sure how the code works, like I said I just copied it. but it seem to do what I require( i.e generate number between 0 and 10). and I did try thinking of alternatives to my main problem but this is the first solution I could think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does the number need to be random?  Can't you just use a static int that gets incremented every time you need to generate a new student number?

Comment: Since the private fields in the class are only accessible from the public member functions and not directly from the main program.

Comment: any number generated needs to be carried from each instance of the class. this is easier than it sounds!!!

Comment: And the constructor when it is run does not know of the existence of other instances of the class until they are declared in the main. this is how I see it anyway. So I believe it is not as straight forward as it sounds when you initially come across this problem.

Comment: I believe jedward above mentioned static member variables. this could be the key to solving this problem

Comment: none of those reasons explains why the student id needs to be *random*.  Add a static variable `static int next_student_id = 0`, then in your constructor do `student_id = next_student_id++`.  Then simply add a `get_student_id()` member function that returns student_id.

Comment: Alan - not sure if that would work, have already tried something similar and I get each instance of the class set as '0' when i try to increment, But I have not tried static int's yet so I will investigate and come back... thanks

Comment: And I don't need random numbers, but 'static int' works out for me

Comment: Correction: And I don't need random numbers, but I initially thought that would need them. Hopefully the 'static int' works out for me.

Comment: Its humorous to me (but not all that surprising) that this answer got the check mark.

Answer (score 2):

Simply have a vector with all possible student ids. in your case 0..Range.

do a [**random_shuffle**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/) and pick the first three ids and assign them

I have added a working solution.

```
//Only have one instance of this class.
class IdMgr
{
    std::vector<int> mIds;
    int mCurrentId;
public:
    IdMgr( int Max )
    {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i <= Max; ++i )
            mIds.push_back( i );

        std::random_shuffle( mIds.begin() , mIds.end() );

        mCurrentId = 0;
    }

    //Call this function from your class constructor
    int GetNextId()
    {
        return mIds[ mCurrentId++];
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes I could this working, I will have to see how a random shuffle works on a vector. But would this still prevent duplicates??

Comment: It would prevent dupicates, but you can't do this from within the constructor like you are asking.  This really doesn't solve the problem and is probably misleading.

Comment: Why won't it work... Just store i = 0 as the last id use. Each class can assign itself an id in the constructor from the vector and increment i afterwards. the id will be random and also not repeat itself

Comment: @Mr_leighman No, `random_shuffle` does not remove the duplicate elements in the container. If you need to remove the duplicates from the container, use [std::unique_copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique_copy/)

Comment: @Mahesh... What do you think random_shuffle does ?

Comment: Even if you did generate the randomized list and pass it to the constructor, you would still need some static member variable to store the last used index.  It doesn't really make sense to do it that way unless you're talking about many many student instances.

Comment: @parapurarajkumar The sentence isn't correctly framed ;) I just noticed I wrote the opposite

Comment: +1. Nice solution. Only need to check if mCurrentId if greater than mIds.size();

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use what is called a **static member variable**.  Usually, each object gets *its own* copy of the member variables.  In your code, each student will have his own copy of `name[25]`, `student_id`, etc.  But what you want, is something that will be shared between each instance of the class (each of the elements in `classroom students[3]` are instances of the `classroom` class.)

Here are some notes on [static member variables](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/811-static-member-variables/).  Note that they present a solution to a very similar problem -- they assign unique IDs to each class instance.  The only difference between what they present here and what you ask for is that you ask for it to be randomized, instead of consecutive.

So instead of a static member variable keeping track of one number (the last one assigned), you will want your static member variable to keep track of *all of the previously assigned ids*.  A std.vector or simple int array should work.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class classroom{
    char name[25];
    int student_id;
    float grades[10];
    float average;
    int num_tests;
    float letter_grade;

    static vector<int> used;

public:       
    void enter_name_id(void);
    void enter_grade(void);
    void average_grades(void);
    void letter_grades(void);
    void output_name_id_grade(void);
    classroom();
};

vector<int> classroom::used = vector<int>();

classroom::classroom(){
    int i;
    int random_integer=0; 
    bool rand_ok;
    do
    {
        // Generate Random Integer
        random_integer = (rand()%5) + (rand()%5); 
        //cout << "Generated: " << random_integer << endl;

        rand_ok = true;
        for(i=0; i<used.size(); i++)
        {
            if(used[i] == random_integer){ rand_ok = false; break; }
        }

    } while (rand_ok == false);

    // If we get here, random_integer is not in the used vector
    // therefore accept and store as student_id
    student_id = random_integer;    
    // ... and update used vector
    used.push_back(student_id);

    num_tests=0;
    average=0.0;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){

    grades[i]=0.0;

    }

    for(i=0;i<27;i++){

     name[i]='-';       
    }
    cout<<"*****************Finished*****************\n";
}


int main()
{       
    // You should only seed the RNG once
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    classroom students[3]; 
}
```

The above code is one way you might do it, by storing the used student ids in a vector, and then every time you create a new student, ensure the randomly generated id doesn't match an already assigned ID.

One other note, you should only seed the random number generator once (especially if your seed is the time).  Since you were seeding it 3 times in such a short time, the random numbers being produced were the same.

Comment: I believe your above answer is along the line of what I need. If I don't need to generate random numbers and just have consecutive numbers that is fine by me, I will just use consecutive numbers as long as I am achieving my aim: which is to uniquely id each instance of the class. Thanks

Comment: The code I provided will generate random unique numbers.  If you want consecutive (also unique) numbers, you can change `static vector<int> used;` to `static int last_used;`, change `vector<int> classroom::used = vector<int>();` to `int classroom::last_used = 0` and replace lines 33-53 of my solution to `student_id = last_used++;`.

Comment: I have a similar setup and it seems that every time I create an instance of my object I get the same result. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

For all those that want to know the solution to my problem of creating a unique id for each instance of a class, here it is:

```
class classroom{

         char name[25];
         int student_id;
         float grades[10];
         float average;
         int num_tests;
         float letter_grade;

         **static int next_student_id;**

  public:       
         void enter_name_id(void);
         void enter_grade(void);
         void average_grades(void);
         void letter_grades(void);
         void output_name_id_grade(void);
         classroom();
  };

         **int classroom::next_student_id=1;**
```

Notice, the new member: **static int next_student_id** has been created and used in the constructor, it has also been initialized outside of the class structure.

In the constructor I simply used the following code:

```
student_id=next_student_id++;
```

This code produced unique consecutive numbers for each instance of the Class classroom structure;
Please note I am aware that Class classroom is not an ideal name as it conflicts with the name of class, but I used this as I copied the basic naming from a text book question!

I have concluded that Alan's answer above helped me the most and provided me with the most simple solution.And so Alan therefore gets a tick from me.

I would like to thank Jedwards also, your answer if pursued could of also been an alternative solution... but as it turns out, using a static int was the key and generating  random numbers and creating vectors was not necessary.

And thank you also parapura rajkumar and other contributors